# Add 2 decimal place in number in Mysql (without rounding up)

Tags: mysql

For example 36829 become 368.29 I just want to add 2 decimal place

```
 Cent   | RM    
 36829  | 368.29
```

Column name cent and I want to convert to RM which just need to add 2 decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Cent,format(Cent/100,2) from yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just use 
Update phone set RM = format(Cent/100,2);